# Anomaly in Magnitude Spectrum plot of an ASK Signal

Tags: fft, sampling, amplitude-modulation

Following is a SciLab code and Plots for Modulation of ASK Signal:
My question is :
For these particular values of fm and t, I get two weird small spikes on either side of main lobe, which doesn't cross zeros. Why is it happening and how to solve it?

```
clear;
clf();
fs=10000;
t=0:1/fs:5//time index
N=length(t);
f=fs*(-N/2:1:N/2-1)/N//freq index
n=length(f)
fm=0.5//modulating freq
fc=20//carrier freq

m=(squarewave(2*%pi*fm*t)+1)/2
c=cos(2*%pi*fc*t)

figure(0)
subplot(3,1,1)
title("Square wave(Modulating Signal)")
xlabel("time(s)")
ylabel("Voltage")
plot(t,m)
gca().data_bounds=[0 -2;5 2]

subplot(3,1,2)
title("Carrier Signal")
xlabel("time(s)")
ylabel("Voltage")
plot(t,c)

ask=m.*c//ASK Signal

subplot(3,1,3)
title("Amplitude Modulated Signal")
xlabel("time(s)")
ylabel("Voltage")
plot(t,ask)

figure(1)
title("Magnitude Spectrum of ASK")
xlabel("freq(Hz)")
ylabel("Magnitude")
plot(f,(fftshift(abs(fft(ask)))/(N/2)))
gca().data_bounds=[-60 0;60 0.7]
```

[image: Time Domain Signals]

[image: Frequency domain Signal]

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying a sine wave with a square wave. Multiplication in the time domain is convolution of transforms in the frequency domain.  The transform of a square wave is a Sinc function, which includes all those ripples on each side, modulating the 2 sine wave spikes containing the frequency of a real square wave.

To get less ripples, use something with smoother corners than a square wave as the modulator, for instance by using raised cosine transitions between zeros and 1's in the data signal.

You can't get rid of the 2 sidebands, since that's what carries the information in the square wave or data.  So the only way to completely get rid of the 2 side spikes is to get rid of the constant frequency modulating data.

Comment: Ok, thankyou very much